# Does all childhood magic duplicate actual spells?

Tags: harry-potter, magic, magical-theory

> On the other hand, he'd gotten into terrible trouble for being found on the roof of the school kitchens. Dudley's gang had been chasing him as usual when, as much to Harry's surprise as anyone else's, there he was sitting on the chimney. The Dursleys had received a very angry letter from Harry's headmistress telling them Harry had been climbing school buildings. But all he'd tried to do (as he shouted at Uncle Vernon through the locked door of his cupboard) was jump behind the big trash cans outside the kitchen doors. Harry supposed that the wind must have caught him in mid- jump.

The one above is like the spell Apparition that Harry can perform. But until 6th year, Harry can’t learn it. Some other mention is Neville who can bounce when dropped, or when Lily manipulated the petal flower.

Can magic in a wizard's childhood be re-executed when they grow up? Or at least the majority of it?

Comment: is like sign of magic before you go to a  magic school

Comment: Since the magic in *Harry Potter* is a mostly ["soft"](https://www.brandonsanderson.com/sandersons-first-law/) magic system, we don't know (and can't really speculate) the full list of spells that exist. So my guess would be "probably."

Comment: That brings another question: Where do all the spells in HP universe come from?

Comment: @TimSparrow They're invented by wizards.

Comment: @Roberto If they're invented by wizards, they wouldn't show up in people who were not taught the spells. It's a chicken or egg.

Comment: @axelonet That doesn't make sense. Children can use accidental, wordless and wandless magic. Wizards invent spells to focus magic and produce the desired effect. There's an essential difference.

Answer (score 1):

It is made evident through the books that children can't control the magic inside them.

In Philosopher's Stone, it is said that Harry caused his hair to grow back in a single night, caused the glass separating Dudley and the snake in the zoo to simply *vanish* and when trying to jump behind the school dustbins, finding himself at the top of the kitchens.

When Marge insults Harry's parents in Prisoner of Azkaban, he loses control over his emotions and causes the glass that Marge was holding, to shatter. Of course, Marge doesn't stop, and that causes her to blow up.

Here, we cannot be sure of whether or not the magic underage wizards perform can be replicated using spells. But, certain ***effects*** of the underage magic **can** be replicated. For example :-

- Shatter glass - Confringo
- Disappear from one place and appear in another - Apparition (As OP mentioned)
- Vanish objects - Evanesco
- Fall from a height without injury - Arresto Momentum

Also, there many underage magic feats that cannot be explained by canon spells. Examples:-

- Bloom and un-bloom a flower rapidly
- Blow up a person such that they start floating
- Growing back your recently-cut hair in one night

There might be more examples of the instances mentioned above, but only these come to my mind at this moment.